# How to find indefinite integral $\int a^{\frac {1}{x}} \mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to find  indefinite integral $$\int a^{\frac {1}{x}} \mathrm dx$$?

The problem is that we can't use the formula for $a^x$.

Any help welcomed

Comment: It is non-elementary.

Comment: That is, there is no "nice" closed form. To find the antiderivative, one would have to resort to infinite series reprensentations and the like...  (A substitution and integrating by parts allows one to write the indefinite integral in terms of the [Exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).)

Comment: is it possible to circumvent exponential integral?

Answer (score 4):

Let $t = \log(a)$. Make $u$-substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$:
$$
    \int \exp\left(\frac{t}{x}\right) \mathrm{d}x = \int \exp\left( t u \right) \mathrm{d} \left(\frac{1}{u}\right) \stackrel{\text{by parts}}{=} \frac{\exp(t u)}{u} - t \int \frac{\exp(t u)}{u} \mathrm{d} u \stackrel{u \to u/t}{=} \left( \frac{\exp(t u}{u} - t \int \frac{\exp(u)}{u} \mathrm{d} u  \right)
$$
The latter integral is [non-elementary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral). A special function [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\operatorname{Ei}(u)$ has the require antiderivative.

Answers to the earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral) is a recommended read.